# How to avoid NoSuchMethodError in docker-client test program

Tags: java, docker, jersey

I am using the following Java test program as a proof of concept for invoking docker-client in a Jersey 1.x project.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final DockerClient docker = 
                new DefaultDockerClient("http://127.0.0.1:4243/");
        final String id = "wg";
        final String[] command = {"bash", "-c", "ps", "-ef"};
        final String execId = docker.execCreate(id, command,
                DockerClient.ExecParameter.STDOUT,
                DockerClient.ExecParameter.STDERR);
        System.out.println("Time before execution = " + new Date());
        final LogStream output = docker.execStart(execId);
        final String execOutput = output.readFully();
        System.out.println("Output of docker exec = " + execOutput);
        System.out.println("Time after execution = " + new Date());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

At runtime I am getting the following error ...

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.(Lcom/spotify/docker/client/shaded/javax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Predicate;)V
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.(ClientConfig.java:146)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:456)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:465)
>           at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.(DefaultDockerClient.java:127)
>           at DockerClientTest.main(DockerClientTest.java:13)

I thought that I might have missed a dependent jar somewhere.  However I downloaded all the dependent jars for docker-client-2.7.7-shared.jar via the Maven command "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies".  Here is the list of jars I am using at runtime ...

```
[cwesley@localhost docker-client]$ ls lib
aopalliance-repackaged-2.3.0-b10.jar  jackson-datatype-guava-2.2.3.jar
asm-4.0.jar                           jackson-jaxrs-base-2.2.3.jar
asm-analysis-4.0.jar                  jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.3.jar
asm-commons-4.0.jar                   jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.2.3.jar
asm-tree-4.0.jar                      javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
asm-util-4.0.jar                      javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.51.jar               javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar               javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar                 jersey-apache-connector-2.13.jar
commons-compress-1.8.1.jar            jersey-client-2.13.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar                  jersey-common-2.13.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar             jersey-guava-2.13.jar
docker-client-2.7.7-shaded.jar        jersey-media-json-jackson-2.13.jar
guava-17.0.jar                        jffi-1.2.7-native.jar
hk2-api-2.3.0-b10.jar                 jffi-1.2.7.jar
hk2-locator-2.3.0-b10.jar             jnr-constants-0.8.6.jar
hk2-utils-2.3.0-b10.jar               jnr-enxio-0.5.jar
httpclient-4.3.5.jar                  jnr-ffi-2.0.0.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar                    jnr-posix-3.0.8.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar         jnr-unixsocket-0.4.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar                jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar            osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.2.3.jar     slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
```

I know that the CommonConfig class is present in jersey-common-2.13.jar.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Could it be related to this bug https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/61 ?

Comment: @rsutormin Thanks for the suggestion.  I updated the bash script that I am using to execute the client program to export "DOCKER_HOST" as an environment variable.  The same error persists.

Comment: Copying answer received on docker-client github site ...  It looks like the shaded 'com/spotify/docker/client/shaded/javax/ws/rs/RuntimeType' is clashing with the non-shaded jersey 2.x libraries, which probably expect 'javax/ws/rs/RuntimeType'. 

The shaded jar contains many of those dependencies needed by docker-client so that you don't need to expose your other projects to Jersey 2.x.

I'm pretty sure that hk2, jackson, jersey, jnr, jffi, javax, asm*, guava, osgi-resource-locator can be removed, and from there I would try launching your example again and seeing what happens.